# What's a polynomial witness for this TSP variation?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

I was thinking about the Travelling Salesman Problem when I thought of a possible variation, the minimum salesman path(MSP).

In the original TSP, the question is to decide whether a path exists through the weighted graph such that the sum of the weights in the path be less than, or equal to some integer, $n$. A polynomial-time witness for this is such a given path.

In the minimum salesman path variation, I ask whether the length of the smallest path in the graph is equal to some integer, $m$ (The path satisfies the TSP route through the nodes).

If we restrict ourselves to non-negative integer values for the weights on the paths, MSP is Turing reducible to TSP. The reduction is achieved thus :

Given a weighted graph, and the value, $m$, we use an algorithm for TSP to decide whether there are any paths with length $\le m$. If yes, then we run TSP algorithm again to check whether there are any paths with length $\le m-1$.

So, MSP Turing reduces to TSP, and is a decision problem. Hence, it should be in the class $NP$, or $Co-NP$ 
But I am unable to find any polynomial-time witness for either acceptance, or rejection.

Can someone provide me with any?

EDIT : changed $\lt$ to $\le$ in the text.

Comment: How do you conclude that "hence, it should be in NP or coNP"?

Comment: 1) It is a decision problem.

2) TSP is atleast as hard as the MSP variation, since MSP Turing reduces to TSP, as I've shown above.

So, it has to be within the set of NP, or Co-NP languages. There's nowhere else to go.

Comment: How do you conclude "So, it has to be within the set of NP, or Co-NP languages"? I don't see how that follows from what you write before. Somewhere else for it to go would be _outside_ NP${}\cup{}$Co-NP.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm fishing for ideas. The only other class it could possibly be in, is PSPACE, Where do you discern this problem to be in?

Comment: I don't know. _You're_ the one making a claim; it's up to you to argue for it. (The problem is obviously in PSPACE, of course. But that does not tell us whether it is also in NP or coNP or both).

Comment: Do you want MSP for some integer or MSP for a given specific integer? If the first, the problem under your restrictions is trivial, the problem is in P. If you want some specific integer, then your reduction is wrong, consider shortest path of length m-0.5.

Comment: MSP for a specific input integer, like how it is for TSP. How does that make my reduction wrong? We're considering graphs which have integer weights on their edges. So, if there is a minimum travelling salesman path of length m, then there won't be one of length m-1.

Comment: @SohanBiswas I'm having a terrible time finding good sources. You're right that you have a Turing reduction. The trouble is that NP it's connected by many to one reductions, which I don't think exists here. Many to one reductions seem to preserve witnesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is known as EXACT-TSP and lives in the complexity class DP. EXACT-TSP was proven DP-complete over thirty years ago in the paper "The complexity of facets (and some facets of complexity)" by C. H. Papadimitriou and M. Yannakakis (see Theorem 2).  As such, there is no polynomial-time witness for this problem unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the first level.

Answer (score -1):

TSP is in $NP$ because there are polynomial-time witnesses for path length $\le m$.  But it is not known to be in Co-$NP$, because there are no known polynomial-time witnesses for length $\ge m$.

EDIT: A polynomial time witness for minimal path length $=m$ would also be a witness for minimal path length $\ge m$.  Thus MSP is not known to be in $NP$.

Comment: I know this, and it doesn't answer my question regarding the variation. I mentioned that the variation, i.e. Minimum Salesman Path (MSP) is either in NP, or Co-NP.

Comment: A decision problem that is Turing reducible to a NP-Complete problem (TSP), but is not in NP. Are there more known examples of this in the literature on complexity?